# Understanding Query Plan of a Spark SQL Query

Tags: apache-spark-sql, spark-ui

I am trying to understand the Physical Plan of a Spark SQL query. I am using Spark SQL v **2.4.7**.
Below is a partial query plan generated for a big query.

```
:     +- ReusedQueryStage 16
:        +- BroadcastQueryStage 7
:           +- BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(input[0, string, true]))
:              +- AdaptiveSparkPlan(isFinalPlan=true)
:                 +- *(11) HashAggregate(keys=[src_clmorigid#21055], functions=[], output=[src_clmorigid#21055])
:                    +- ShuffleQueryStage 21, true
:                       +- Exchange hashpartitioning(src_clmorigid#21055, 10)
:                          +- *(10) HashAggregate(keys=[src_clmorigid#21055], functions=[], output=[src_clmorigid#21055])
:                             +- *(10) Project [src_clmorigid#21055]
:                                +- *(10) BroadcastHashJoin [tgt_clmorigid#21152], [tgt_clmorigid#20756], Inner, BuildRight
:                                   :- *(10) Project [src_clmorigid#21055, tgt_clmorigid#21152]
:                                   :  +- *(10) Filter (isnotnull(tgt_clmorigid#21152) && isnotnull(src_clmorigid#21055))
:                                   :     +- *(10) FileScan parquet default.vw_exclude_latest_set_frm_clm[src_clmorigid#21055,tgt_clmorigid#21152] Batched: true, Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[s3://dm_bucket...
:                                   +- ReusedQueryStage 20
:                                      +- BroadcastQueryStage 6
:                                         +- BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(input[0, string, true]))
:                                            +- AdaptiveSparkPlan(isFinalPlan=true)
:                                               +- *(9) HashAggregate(keys=[tgt_clmorigid#20756], functions=[], output=[tgt_clmorigid#20756])
:                                                  +- ShuffleQueryStage 19, true
:                                                     +- Exchange hashpartitioning(tgt_clmorigid#20756, 10)
:                                                        +- *(8) HashAggregate(keys=[tgt_clmorigid#20756], functions=[], output=[tgt_clmorigid#20756])
:                                                           +- *(8) Project [tgt_clmorigid#20756]
:                                                              +- *(8) Filter ((((isnotnull(tgt_clm_line_type_ind#20783) && isnotnull(src_clm_line_type_ind#20686)) 
:                                                                 +- *(8) FileScan parquet default.vw_exclude_latest_set_frm_clm[src_clm_line_type_ind#20686,tgt_clmorigid#20756,tgt_clm_line_type_ind#20783] Batched: true, Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[s3://...PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(tgt_clm_line_type_ind), 
                                                                      +- *(41) Project [vw_clm_base_fact_sk#21807, source_system#21808, eff_date#21809, frst_sales_crtn_dt#21810, clmorigid#21811, ... 59 more fields]
                                                                          +- *(41) FileScan parquet default.vw_to_be_merged_data[vw_clm_base_fact_sk#21807,source_system#21808,eff_date#21809,frst_sales_crtn_dt#21810,... 56 more fields], ...
```

Can anyone please help me answer the following questions I have:

- What are the numbers inside parenthesis signify ? E.g. `*(41)`, `*(8)`
  etc. Does it represent `Stage Id` or `WholeStageCodeGen Id` ?
- I understand that the asterisk '`*`' represent `WholeStageCodegen`. What
  does that exactly mean and what is the significance in terms of query performance ? Few days
  back I saw a Spark SQL query Physical Plan that did
  not contain any asterisks - which means no `wholestagecodegen`. Does
  that mean the sql query was poorly written and hence performance
  of that query will be suboptimal ? What causes `wholestagecodegen` to
  be not utilized by Spark optimizer as in that specific query ?
- What does "`ReusedQueryStage 20`" mean in the above query plan ? What
  does the number `20` signify ?
- What does "`BroadcastQueryStage 6`" mean in the above query plan ? What
  does the number `6` signify ?
- What does "`ShuffleQueryStage 21`" mean in the above query plan ? What
  does the number `21` signify ?
- What does "`AdaptiveSparkPlan(isFinalPlan=true)`" mean in the above
  query plan ?
- I once saw an execution plan of a query in the SQL tab of the
  Spark UI which had an operator called "`BloomFilter`". What does that
  mean ? Is it something regarding reading a parquet file ? Can you please explain.

A question regarding Spark UI:

- In the `Stages` tab of Spark UI (spark SQL 2.4.7), the DAGs often
  contain boxes labelled "`WholeStageCodeGen`" which contains several
  operators in the same box. What does this signify in Spark with
  respect to query performance ?
- The DAGs shown in the Stages tab of Spark UI do not show
  which part of the actual query it pertains to, since it does not show
  any specific table-name etc. Hence with big queries it often becomes
  very difficult to pinpoint the exact part of the query that the DAG
  pertains to. Is there any way to identify the exact part of the code
  which pertains to that specific Stage in the DAG ?

*Note: I am using Spark 2.4.7*

Can anyone please help me answer the above questions. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.